# Is it possible to get the size of an array of function pointers as like normal arrays?

Tags: c

Trying to get the size of an array of function pointers through below code,
   it is giving compilation error. Please confirm whether it is possible to 
   get the size, as like normal array.

```
   int (*fptr[])(int) = { get_square, get_cube, get_square_root };

   printf("\nsize = %d", sizeof((*fptr[])(int)));
```

Comment: As usual: `sizeof(ftpr) / sizeof(fptr[0])`.

Comment: The name of the array is `fptr`. You get the size of the array with `sizeof(fptr)`. If you need the number of items in the array, you use the code from Eugene's comment `sizeof(fptr)/sizeof(fptr[0])`.

Comment: Note that the correct format for printing `size_t` with [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is `"%zu"`.

Comment: @SathyapramodhV: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

You can't `sizeof` an unbounded array. You want `sizeof(fptr)/sizeof(fptr[0])` as Eugene pointed out in comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the size of an array of function pointers just like any other array:

- the size in bytes is `sizeof(fptr)` or simply `sizeof fptr`
- the number of elements is `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`.

Beware however that `sizeof` evaluates (at compile time) to a value of type `size_t` which is different from `int`. To print it, use:

```
    int (*fptr[])(int) = { get_square, get_cube, get_square_root };

    printf("size = %zu bytes\n", sizeof fptr);
    printf("size = %zu elements\n", sizeof(fptr) / sizeof(fptr[0]));
```

Or possibly cast to `unsigned` if your C library does not support the C99 size modifiers:

```
    printf("size = %u bytes\n", (int)sizeof fptr);
    printf("size = %u elements\n", (int)(sizeof(fptr) / sizeof(fptr[0])));
```